# Upload file not allowed jquery upload function

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

Im building a file upload module to upload images on my website.

Im using Uikit upload plugin. http://getuikit.com/docs/upload.html

The console says this on upload

```
405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I have found some stuff about a handler or something but im completly stuck here please help me!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Check you directory, set chmod to 775 or 777